# MVC Authentication Filter called after page load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have my own custom Authentication Filter that I use to determine user roles from cookie values that our Single Sign-On solution provides to all of our applications. We then create cookies that are specific to the application. The problem I am running into is that it seems that the Authentication Filter is being called after the page load has already begun.

Ive added the attribute below to my Controller action.

```
[Authentication(AuthenticationHelper.ADMIN)]
```

This is my implementation of the ActionFilterAttribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AuthenticationAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute, System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string _role;
    private List<string> _roles = new List<string>();

    public AuthenticationAttribute()
    {
    }

    public AuthenticationAttribute(string role)
    {
        _roles.Add(role);
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext is null");
        }

        AuthenticationHelper user = new AuthenticationHelper(filterContext.HttpContext.Request);
        var userRole = user.GetRole();

        if (userRole == null || (userRole != null && !_roles.Contains(userRole))) 
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Home/NotAuthorized");
        }
    }
    public string Role
    {
        get { return _role; }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to have this execute before the page load begins, or is there any other way to create cookies before the page load has begun so that the application can read them?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you describe what do you mean by page load and when do you want it to run instead? Of course the request processing HAS to begin before any filters are run, but I believe it runs before your controller method, doesn't it?

Comment: Why do you derive from ActionFilter?  ActionFilters execute much later than you want...

Comment: @fejesjoco The problem is what you identified in your last sentence. It executes after the controller has already started its processing.

Comment: @ErikTheViking what else would I be able to derive from to create an attribute that would still allow me to use it as an Authentication attribute?

Comment: @atrljoe - You can derive from AuthorizeAttribute

Comment: An authentication filter shouldn't derive from `AuthorizeAttribute` either. It can derive from `FilterAttribute`...although the implementation here does look like it's doing authorization and not authentication in spite of the name.